# change nested span style has style tag using css

Tags: html, css, wordpress, themes, wordpress-theming

I am using a theme in wordpress framework and I made some articles with nested titles like ..

```
 * FooFoo Title
```

```
    rest of article
```

and I make the color of title (FooFoo Title) Black then a Theme updated with a Dark style so the black titles no longer visible so I tried to change the colors it appear like that ..

```
<h5> <span style="color: red">FooFoo Title</span> </h5>
```

so I went to Theme Settings and make a new attribute in Custom-CSS and it's not working unless I disable the color in (span style tag) using (Developer Tools) in browser.

I can't edit all my 1000 articles titles .. So help me .. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding `!important` to your styles?

Example:

```
h5 span {color: blue !important;}
```

EDIT: **USE `!important` ONLY WHEN ABSOLUTELY NEEDED!**

Idealy you should **remove** the **inline styles** and the **!important** from your css!

Comment: Wasn't me who downvoted you, but using `!important` is a generally bad idea and shouldn't be necessary here at all.

Comment: Using inline styling is a bad idea too, but since Hady Shaltout is using it, I provided a working solution... I love random downvoters!

Comment: Avoid !important at all costs! IMO

Comment: Again, avoid inline styling at all costs, but since it is being used, here is a solution.

Comment: While !important is bad practice, it's a perfectly fine way to override inline styles.